# Wordpress - Function parameters not passing in

Tags: wordpress, email, hook, php

I am trying to write a function that emails my users after I publish a new post. Here is what I have so far:

```
require_once('db.php');

$sql="SELECT email FROM table";

$result = sqlsrv_query($sqlsrvconnection, $sql);

$emailList="";

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $emailList.=", ".$row['email'];
}

add_action('save_post', 'email_members');

function email_members( $post_id, $emailList )  {

    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

        $to      = 'example@test.com';
        $subject = 'the subject';
        $message = "email list consists of: ".$emailList;
        $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}

}
```

In my function I have tried to pass in the $emailList variable, but I am not able to do anything with it. Am I passing it in wrong? Is this not allowed when hooking into another wp action?

Comment: may ask what this is? it doesnt look coherent.. are you trying to get an email from the users table? it seems like your making something easy more complex then need ie: sql queries like that.. am I missing something? can you elaborate on your goals?

Comment: @DavidChase I am selecting emails from a pre-existing database that is separate from the WP database. Otherwise I would use wpdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my function is called somewhere else (with the save_post action). Because of this, the function didn't have access to the $emailList variable. I moved everything (except for the add_action()) inside the function and everything worked great!

```
add_action('save_post', 'email_members');

function email_members( $post_id, $emailList )  {

    require_once('db.php');

    $sql ="SELECT email FROM table";

    $result = sqlsrv_query($sqlsrvconnection, $sql);

    $emailList="";

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $emailList.=", ".$row['email'];
    }

    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

        $to      = 'example@test.com';
        $subject = 'the subject';
        $message = "email list consists of: ".$emailList;
        $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    }

}
```